# Many diseases are titled "The Silent Killer" while they are "A Silent Killer"

Tags: grammatical-number

Why use The instead of A?  Perhaps the writers of The are pulling at our emotions.

Comment: I thought high blood pressure was "*the* silent killer" because there are no typical symptoms. (I think this might be off-topic).

Comment: I'd say "Silent Killer" on it's own stands as sufficient evidence of an attempt to pull at emotions, no? It's not like its a logic-based statement. Logically it makes more sense to point out the noisy killers: "Pertussis, Tuberculosis, Firearms; The Noisy Killers".

Comment: @Jon: In the biomed field, silent killers are asymptomatic diseases like hypertension & certain types of cancer that have no easily discernible signs & symptoms until they've progressed to stage III (advanced) or IV (terminal). In journalese, "silent killer" may be a heart-string harpist, but for medical types, it's a motivation to search for biochemical markers in blood, urine, & breath tests, e.g. Typically, the idiom isn't logical.

Answer (score 2):

Calling something *the silent killer* does not necessarily mean it is the exclusive silent killer, simply that it is the one of central interest in a particular context. If I am borrowing someone's computer and ask "what is the password?" to log on, I am asking for a password that will work for me, regardless of the fact that there may be dozens of active accounts and thus dozens of working passwords on that computer.

Advocates creating a public service advertising campaign in order to raise the profile of a particular topic would always want to use *the* instead of *a*. Calling [carbon monoxide](http://www.silentshadow.org/), or [hypertension](http://www.health.harvard.edu/special_health_reports/Hypertension), or [chronic inflammation](http://news.sciencemag.org/sciencenow/2012/05/silent-killer-may-be-disease-of-.html) *the silent killer* suggests that it is, if not the only silent killer, perhaps the most important among them (at least until the next PSA comes on). *A silent killer* is just one of a bunch— and not necessarily the worst of the bunch.

Nor is the habit limited to health activists. Why, just in carbonated soft drink slogans alone, off the top of my head, I recall

- *The Real Thing*
- *The Choice of a New Generation*
- *The pause that refreshes*
- *The Right One*
- *The Uncola*
- *Just what the doctor ordered*

which all imply a uniqueness to the flavored sugar water contained in a can bearing certain logos, as opposed to that in cans with other logos.

Comment: This is _the_ excellent answer on how context can affect article selection. Nice!